# Minecraft Crashes When Pressing 'f11'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft crashes whenever I go in full screen mode or out of full screen mode using f11 or using the option in the in-game settings.

When I say crashes, I really mean the game just turns into a white screen. I can still hear the sounds though. It doesn't send me back to the launcher with a crash message like normal crashes, either. That made me not able to report to Mojang, because I didn't have a crash message.

Does anybody have a fix to this? I've searched on Google, but I couldn't find an answer that directly related to my problem. I've also searched on here, but I also couldn't find a good solution that worked for me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: this seems to be a problem with your graphics card. Update your drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with your GPU drivers. Visit the website of your graphics card manufacturer (Intel, NVIDIA, AMD) and look for graphics drivers for your operating system.

---

*Note: You may have more trouble with this if you have a Windows insider version of a windows OS installed on your PC*